# Масштабирование в компоненте webBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms

Как масштабировать размер содержимого в компоненте webBrowser1 выбирая уже заготовленные варианты масштаба в виде "25%", "50%", "100%", "150%", "200%" через отдельные button'ы или ComboBox1?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738232/zoom-in-on-a-web-page-using-webbrowser-net-control

Comment: Покажите пользователю подсказку (напишите в документации к вашему софту), что он может масштабировать содержимое колёсиком мышки, нажав при этом Ctrl.

Comment: Нужно именно так как я описал...

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
   comboBox1.Items.Add("100%");
   comboBox1.Items.Add("150%");
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  webBrowser1.Document.Body.Style = "zoom:" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + ";";
}
```

Comment: Если страница сама использует зум, то что-то поломается. Но вообще, должно бы подойти.